# jQuery Mobile - Inner #page navigation only work with double-click when page first loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

When I load a jQuery multi-page the #hashed inner-page links work only after I refresh the page.

I.e. 
http://value.holiday/go/to/United_States_of_America/Albuquerque

Clicking directly on the image the click just "evaporates".
Reloading the page and doing it again it works.

Am I missing something basic here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Turns out this had nothing to do with the actual page, but was caused by the fact that this page had been loaded via jQmobile. Adding

```
          data-ajax="false"
```

to the corresponding href
did the trick.